# ngFileUpload and Multer - saving uploaded file to a folder

Tags: javascript, angularjs, file-upload, multer, ng-file-upload

I'm (very) new to angular MEAN and I'm trying to upload a file (pdf, specifically) and save it to server. I know it's probably a stupid question, but I cannot find any example on the server on how to actually save the uploaded file to the server's storage

I'm using ng-file-upload directive from https://github.com/danialfarid/ng-file-upload, Express for server, and ofc, AngularJS for the file upload.

**POST UPDATED!! See below**

More info: I'm using Yeoman's full mean stack generator for this project

**UPDATE:**
I've tried using multer (https://github.com/expressjs/multer) to save the uploaded file to server. I got this error when trying to upload the file (it returns 500 error)

```
Error: Unexpected field
   at makeError ({proj_folder}/node_modules/multer/lib/make-error.js:12:13)
   at wrappedFileFilter ({proj_folder}/node_modules/multer/index.js:39:19)
   at Busboy.<anonymous> ({proj_folder}/node_modules/multer/lib/make-middleware.js:112:7)
   at emitMany (events.js:127:13)
   at Busboy.emit (events.js:201:7)
   at Busboy.emit ({proj_folder}/node_modules/busboy/lib/main.js:31:35)
   at PartStream.<anonymous> ({proj_folder}/node_modules/busboy/lib/types/multipart.js:213:13)
   at emitOne (events.js:96:13)
   at PartStream.emit (events.js:188:7)
   at HeaderParser.<anonymous> ({proj_folder}/node_modules/dicer/lib/Dicer.js:51:16)
   at emitOne (events.js:96:13)
   at HeaderParser.emit (events.js:188:7)
   at HeaderParser._finish ({proj_folder}/node_modules/dicer/lib/HeaderParser.js:68:8)
   at SBMH.<anonymous> ({proj_folder}/node_modules/dicer/lib/HeaderParser.js:40:12)
   at emitMany (events.js:127:13)
   at SBMH.emit (events.js:201:7)
```

**updated HTML**

```
<form accept-charset="UTF-8" class="form" name="form" ng-submit="$ctrl.submitForm(form)" 
                enctype="multipart/form-data">
...
<input ngf-select ng-model="$ctrl.paperFile" ngf-model-options="{allowInvalid: true}" name="paper" ngf-accept="'application/pdf'" required="" type="file" >
...
</form>
```

**submitForm** method

```
...
    this.Upload.upload({
            url:'/paperUpload',
            method: 'POST',
            file: this.paperFile,
            fields:{
              _id:this.user._id
            }
          })
          .then(function(resp){
             console.log('Success upload');
             console.log(resp.data);
          }, function(error){
            console.log('fail upload');
            console.log(error);
          }, function(evt){
            console.log('upload on progress');
            console.log(evt);
          });
```

**Server route:**

```
var express = require('express');
var multer = require('multer');
var router = express.Router();
var upload = multer({dest:'uploads/',
    rename: function(fieldname, filename){
        return filename+"_"+Date.now(); 
    }});
router.post('/paperUpload', upload.single('paper'), uploadPaper);

...

//method to upload
export function uploadPaper(req,res){
  res.status(204).end();
}
```

The folder 'uploads' is created, but the file is not uploaded and always returned fail

Any help is appreciated,
Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Do these steps

1. npm install ng-file-upload
2. include ng-file-upload.min.js in your angular index .html
3. Use this example to copy form to your angular page from where u want to upload file. -- http://jsfiddle.net/0m29o9k7/
   Copy this code outside of any form which is already there:
4. Change this url from example code to where you want to upload files -- url: 'https://angular-file-upload-cors-srv.appspot.com/upload',
5. In your server.js or app.js which ever you are using as (node server.js) to start app add these lines

   var crypto = require('crypto');
       var mime = require('mime');
       var multer  = require('multer');

   ```
   var storage = multer.diskStorage({
     destination: function (req, file, cb) {
       cb(null, 'app/app-content/images/')
     },
     filename: function (req, file, cb) {
       crypto.pseudoRandomBytes(16, function (err, raw) {
         cb(null, raw.toString('hex') + Date.now() + '.' + mime.extension(file.mimetype));
       });
     }
   });

   var upload = multer({ storage: storage });

   // make '/app' default route
   app.post('/', upload.any(), function (req, res) { 
       res.send(req.files);
   });
   ```

Change 'app/app-content/images/' this where you want your uploaded file will be

This code points your file upload url to index of your node server.
then you will be able to see the uploaded file.

Answer (score 0):

Try this, I have never seen the 'file' or 'fields' options of Upload.upload. Do you know those are working? I just overcame a similar error by adding the arrayField to my POST call.
if you get the same error try removing 'fields' and adding a new key to the data object with the _id you wish to pass along.

```js
this.Upload.upload({
            url:'/paperUpload',
            method: 'POST',
            headers: {
                'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data ; boundary = ----WebKitFormBoundaryvlb7BC9EAvfLB2q5'
            },
            arrayKey: '',
            data: {
              paper: this.paperFile,
            },
            fields:{
              _id:this.user._id
            }
          })
          .then(function(resp){
             console.log('Success upload');
             console.log(resp.data);
          }, function(error){
            console.log('fail upload');
            console.log(error);
          }, function(evt){
            console.log('upload on progress');
            console.log(evt);
          });
```